# OnEdit, replace entered text with selected value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to add a custom function (first time doing this) in google sheets but am struggling to get the code working. I have this in my sheet script right now:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range
  if (range.value >= 0 && range.value <= 4 ) {
    range.setValue(['○', '◔', '◑', '◕', '●'][n]);
  }
}
```

but get an error on line 2 that says this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")
```

I can't seem to figure this one out...

Comment: `onEdit` is not custom function, it's trigger. Do you want to launch the function from sheet? What result are you expecting? Is it 0 = ○, 1 = ◔ etc?

Comment: yep, I want to use it as a trigger, I also want it to work on the range F15:F52....and the results are I'm expecting is what you're saying...

Answer (score 1):

**Basic function**

Here's custom function for getting symbol from list:

```
function getSymbol(n) {
  var Symbols = ['○', '◔', '◑', '◕', '●'];
    if (n >=0 && n <=4) {
      return Symbols[n];
    }

    return 'not found';

}
```

---

**Usage of formula**

but there's faster way: use formula.
Add new Sheet 'Symbols' and paste this:

```
A  B
0  ○
1  ◔
2  ◑
3  ◕
4  ●
```

and then use formula:

```
 = vlookup(A2, Symbols!$A:$B, 2, 0)
```

---

**OnEdit Code**

If you want the code to fill symbol into a cell when value [0-4] is entered, use this code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var mySheetName = "Sheet1"; // change to yours
    var myRangeAddress = "F15:F52"; // change to yours

    var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ss = SS.getActiveSheet();
    var myRange = e.range;
    var targetRange = ss.getRange(myRangeAddress);



    if (ss.getName() == mySheetName && RangeIntersect(targetRange, myRange)) {
        var myVal = myRange.getValue();
        var Symbol = getSymbol(myVal);
        myRange.setValue(Symbol);
    }

}

function getSymbol(n) {
  var Symbols = ['○', '◔', '◑', '◕', '●'];
    if (n >=0 && n <=4) {
      return Symbols[n];
    }

    return 'not found';

}

function RangeIntersect(R1, R2) {

  var LR1 = R1.getLastRow();
  var Ro2 = R2.getRow();
  if (LR1 < Ro2) return false;


  var LR2 = R2.getLastRow();
  var Ro1 = R1.getRow();
  if (LR2 < Ro1) return false;

  var LC1 = R1.getLastColumn();
  var C2 = R2.getColumn();
  if (LC1 < C2) return false;

  var LC2 = R2.getLastColumn();
  var C1 = R1.getColumn();
  if (LC2 < C1) return false;

return true;

}
```

Comment: got this one to work...but I'd still like to get it working via onEdit